# ITK 4.9 error LNK2019 for itksys::SystemInformationImplementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, itk

I've seen so far lots of posts which suggested to resolve this problem by including the missing library. Which does not work in my case.

I'm trying to link my project to ITK (v4.9).
The compilation of ITK went just fine, both in debug and release mode. Then I built the project INSTALL and BAM, all the libraries and .h files were in one location.

The project is compiled in Visual Studio 2012.

I included the folder /ITK/include/ in the include field, the /ITK/lib/ as directory of the additional dependencies and the list of .lib(s) in the additional dependencies.

Results? Doesn't work.

```
  Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol gethostbyname 
  referenced in function "public: int __cdecl     
  itksys::SystemInformationImplementation::GetFullyQualifiedDomainName
           (class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &)" (?GetFullyQualifiedDomainName@SystemInformationImplementation@itksys@@QEAAHAEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
```

same error for GetHostname, GetProcessMemoryInfo, GetProcMemoryUsed

what should I do know?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Include the folder :

```
/ITK/Module/Core/Common/include/
```

Above directory contains all the itksys references.

Comment: same error. I'm new to VS and Microsoft in general: if I include a directory, say ITK/Module/Core/ shouldn't be be sub directories automatically included?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution helps someone because I had the same error when using itk v4.13. The issues comes not from not including all the itk libs but the itk libs calling a function that is defined in another external lib, in this case the sdk version being used in the project. To fix this you can read about the following:

1. Read about this in [Windows Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo)
2. See the following thread [CodeGuru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?394011-RESOLVED-error-in-program-compilation-header-file)

Or you can include the following missing lib under the Project properties>Linker>Input>Additonal Dependies: Psapi.lib